# overriding template file of display suite layout applies on other pages

Tags: 7, theming, display-suite

I created a display suite layout "tow column stacked" in manage user section, then I want to override that template, and make a new one in my theme templates folder,
the ds module suggest for me :

> - ds-2col-stacked--user.tpl.php
> - ds-2col-stacked--user-user.tpl.php

so I created `ds-2col-stacked--user-user.tpl.php` in my templates folder, but this template is overriding as well the registration page!

how can override with the correct name, to apply this new template only for user edit account page `("/user/%/edit")` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use hook theme suggestion in your template file. It gives you the right way of naming you tpl file.

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  print_r($variables['theme_hook_suggestions']);

}

function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
  print_r($variables['theme_hook_suggestions']);

}
```